# No cookie value on other pages

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

The page im posting to has the following code, and echo's the cookie correctly:

```
/* verify.php */

if ($age >= "21"  && $location == "USA" && $cookie == "Y") {

    $value = "1";
    setcookie("age_verified", $value, time()+60*60*24*30);
    header("Location: ../portal.php?cookieset");
}
elseif ($age >= "21" && $location == "USA") {

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['age_verified'] = "1";
    header("Location: ../portal.php?sessionset");   
}
```

On portal.php i am not able to echo the cookie, but the session shows up fine if that option is chosen.

```
/* portal.php */

session_start();
echo $_SESSION["age_verified"];
```

Result is "1"

```
/* portal.php */

echo $_COOKIE["age_verified"];
```

No Result

I'm trying to achieve something like the code block below, but it's not working properly since cookie doesn't echo a result
    /* portal.php */
    session_start();

```
if($_SESSION['age_verified']!="1"){
    header("Location: index.php?no_session");
}
elseif ($_COOKIE['age_verified']!="1"){
    header("Location: index.php?no_cookie");
}
else{
    echo "";    
}
```

What am i missing?

Comment: This isn't the problem you're having, but don't use relative paths in `Location:` headers.  While most browsers work with them, they are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that `$_SESSION['age_verified']!="1"||$_COOKIE['age_verified']!="1"` is checking against EITHER session or cookie values. Cookie values are more persistent as they are stored on the user's machine, and session values only persist to a browsing session. They may not both be set.

In fact, looking at your logic on `verify.php` you are performing one action OR the other, not both. Hope this helps.

Comment: ok i see what you're saying but why can't i echo the cookie value on portal.php if it was set on verify.php?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the cookie was definitely set on the `verify` page (output the cookie before the redirect)? Have you tried `print_r($_COOKIE);`? The browser is definitely accepting cookies?

Comment: Yes on verify.php i echo the cookie before the redirect to test and the value comes up fine, but after the redirect it seems the cookie value is lost